# GitLab rejects force push on not protected branches

Tags: git, gitlab

Our GitLab currently rejects force push on not protected branches in a single project, but I don't can't find the issues (I removed already all protection for tags and branches to test it). Is there any log file, where I can find the reason? Force push is working for another project on the same instance of GitLab, so it must be a project related configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check denyNonFastforwards = true in config of gitlab. This is preventing git to push forced updates.

git push --force

You can access git repository and set

git config receive.denynonfastforwards false

Comment: Thanks, this setting was indeed present. I changed it now via command line and now it works :-). Is there any UI for this option in Gitlab? I don't believe anyone of us edited this config until now, so I want to know, where someone could has set it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the gitlab log files.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html

Also what is the message from git when you try to push ?

Comment: remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/test (you should pull first)
! [remote rejected]     test -> test (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...'

@Logs: `git_json.log` doesn't exists and `githost.log` is empty. In `gitlab-shell.log` i don't see my try.